# Add item of a list after every gene sequence

Tags: python-3.x, bioinformatics, biopython

I had split a genome sequence into separate genes and I want to write them in a text file. I want to add a title (name of the gene) before each gene sequence. I have created a list of gene names to be added as title. They need to be added in the same order as given in the list. This is the code I tried:

```py
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i in genes:
        for rec in i:
            for name in Features:               
                print(">" + name, file = f)
            print(rec.seq, file = f)
            print("\n", file = f)
            break
```

Features is the list containing the names of genes.
The output for this code is:

```
>Anchored capsid protein:
>C:
>membrane glycoprotein precursor M:
>protein PR:
>M:
>E:
>NSI:
>NS2A:
>NS2B:
>NS3:
>NS4A:
>NS4B:
>NS5:
>
ATGAATA...
```

When it should be:

```
>Anchored capsid protein:
ATGAATA...
>C:
ATGAATA...
>membrane protein:
TTCCATT...
>precursor:
TTCCATT...
```

Comment: What does the output currently look like when you run this? its better to provide a minimal complete exmple that people can run and help improve. Right now we cannot run your code as we dont have all the data.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Will add the output

Comment: I've edited the question to make things easier to read and to format the code. Could you add some example input? For example, what are the variables `genes` and `Features`? Have a look at [`SeqIO`](https://biopython.org/wiki/SeqIO) look at the section titled **Sequence Output**

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the structure of your lists, this might work:

```py
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i in genes:
        for name, rec in zip(Features, i):
            f.write(">{}\n{}\n".format(name, rec.seq))
        break
```

Comment: Thanks, I got the output by zipping Features in the first for loop. My input file was a clustal file and the sequences would lose their Seq Features if zipped. Thanks for your help